# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority "......" but TLS is set in the code. Works fine on local machine but not in Production

Tags: c#, security, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying this code to reach an API but it doesn't work on PROD server and I don't know why. In local it works fine on my laptop.

```
                            /*ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;*/
                            _client = new HttpBinding<ThalentoWebservicePortType>(@Uri, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.Soap11, (binding, httpTransport, address, factory) =>
                            { 
                                            var basicAuthBehavior = new BasicAuthBehavior(UserName, Password); 
                                            factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(basicAuthBehavior);
                            });
```

I'm working with .NET Framework 4.6.1

Thanks a lot for your help because I'm lost with this issue... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Make sure the prod server (and client of course) is itself capable of TLS1.2 - some windows server versions had to get it via update, and given net461 I guess you work in a rather slow moving company similar to me. With 2016 it's enabled by default, but I think 2012 needs and update.

In case you're still running a 2008 server - upgrade it to a newer one. That one is EOL.

Comment: Hi Sandy, and thanks for your help :-) We found the issue. It was related to the API server on which we request. They had TLS installed but with a cypher not compatible with our Windows Server 2012 R2. They only had a cypher fo Windows Server 2016 or higher... Now they installed the right cypher for us and it works :-) We are rescued :p Have a nice day!